# Yeoman gruntfile not copying css to dist

Tags: css, gruntjs, yeoman, bundling-and-minification

I'm using the default yeoman angular generator and gruntfile.js. I'm running grunt build and none of my css files are being copied to the dist folder. Here is how I have it configured

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/stylish-portfolio.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/animations.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/brettfont.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/brettfont2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/brettfont3.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/font-mfizz-1.2/font-mfizz.css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Help needed here